# A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: dart

Estoy comenzando con dart y he estado intentando hacer una entrada y salida de usuario, pero tengo este error:

> A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
> right-hand type to 'String'.

Aquí el pequeño código:

```
import 'dart:io';
     
main(){
    //Esto es para cuando el usuario quiera ingresar por teclado 
    stdout.writeln('¿Como te llamas: ?');

    String name = stdin.readLineSync(); //linea del error
    print('My name is $name');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se soluciona agregando el símbolo `?` al tipo de dato `String`, porque puede que el valor que agregues por medio de la consola sea nulo, entonces lo que das a entender al momento de implementar el símbolo, es que esta variable puede ser nula:

```
String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
```